# videojs and fancybox - autoplay issues Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fancybox, video.js

videojs is working fine and autoplay works on IE and FF, but not on Chrome.
Google leads to topics from 2012. Can't believe it's not fixed?

Here's my setup:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js?4" >    </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css?4" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="/video-js/creadoo/video-js.less?2" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.5/video.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("a.fancyvideo5").click(function () {
   var url = $(this).attr('name');
    $.fancybox({
        'padding': 7,
        'overlayOpacity': 0.9,
        'width': 588,
        'height': 331,
        'transitionOut': 'elastic',
        'transitionIn': 'elastic',
        'scrolling': 'no',
        'content': '<div class="video-js-box">' +
                   '<video autoplay class="video-js" width="588" height="331" controls preload="none" data-setup='{'autoplay': true}'>' +
                   '<source src="' + url + '"' + 'type=video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' + '/> ' +
                    '</video>' +
                    '</div>',
    });
}); 


});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<a class="fancyvideo5" name="/data/marabu.mp4"><img src="/news/thumb/marabu.jpg" width="588" height="331" alt="Film" /></a> 
</body>
```

Comment: try using http://mediaelementjs.com/ instead

Comment: try using the javascript setup instead of data-setup when the modal box is opened.